# resolve macro variable in sgplot series curvelabel

Tags: graph, sas

```
%let MTDAvg = 33.3;

proc sgplot data=mydata ;
vbarparm category=Day response=Sale1 / group=Dow barwidth=0.7 nooutline datalabel dataskin=pressed name="Daily"; 
series x=Day y=Sale2 / lineattrs=(color=grey pattern=solid thickness=1.5) name="Weekly" ;
series x=Day y=Sale3 / lineattrs=(color=red pattern=solid thickness=2) curvelabel='Avg:%cmpres(&MTDAvg)';
keylegend "Daily" / position=topright noborder autoitemsize;
xaxis display=(nolabel) offsetmax=0.08 labelattrs=(color=pab size=0.5); 
yaxis grid min=10 max=55;
inset 'Avg:%cmpres(&MTDAvg)' / noborder position=topright;
run;
```

Use above code, `inset` statement will place `Avg:33.3` on the topright corner.
But `curvelabel` cannot resolve macro variable and returns `'Avg:%cmpres(&MTDAvg)` at the end of series `series x=Day y=Sale3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it might be a simple fix, you need `"` around macro variables, not `'`.